# Force optaplanner to break specific rules

Tags: break, rules, optaplanner

how to force optaplanner to break specific rules and pass specific rules out of a given set of rules.
I tried to put  a high negative score on the rules that have to pass but no luck.
Also salience did not work. If  2 specific rules are broken the score can be minimum and the solution will be the best. But optaplanner does not give this minimum score and i am not able to force optaplanner to break the specific rules.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you may need a third rule that returns the minimum if the conditions of the two rules are broken.  The other two rules would need to have corresponding logic that determines if the rule should should return a value.